# jquery autocomplete not working, if id change via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I use `jquery` `autocomplete` in searching data from my database and it is working fine in static way, but if I change the input `id` depend on `select` `value` using jquery the `autocomplete` will not work even the `id` is already change.

**html**

```
<select name="report_type" id="report_type"><!--remove space from select and option tag-->
    <option value="" required disabled> Others
        </option>
            <?php 
            $others = array('province' => 'Province', 'city' => 'City/Municipality
', '
ethnicity ' => '
Ethnicity ', '
Religion ' => '
Religion ');
            foreach($others as $key => $others){
              echo "<option ";
              //if($year === $yl){echo "selected";}
              echo " value=\"{$key}\">{$others}</option>";
            }
          ?>

                </select>



    <input id="change_me" class="type" type="text" name="category" value="" placeholder="Search here..." />
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#report_type").change(function() {
            $("input.type").attr("id", $(this).val() + "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**jquery autocomplete**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var initAutocomplete = function($el, dataUrl) {
      var autocompleteOptions = { selectFirst: true, delay:0};
      $el.autocomplete(dataUrl, autocompleteOptions);
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var $province, $city, $religion, $ethnicity,


      $province = $('#province');
      initAutocomplete($province, "search/province.php");


      $city = $('#city');
      initAutocomplete($city, "search/city.php");


      $religion = $('#religion');
      initAutocomplete($religion, "search/religion.php");

      $ethnicity = $('#ethnicity');
      initAutocomplete($ethnicity, "search/ethnicity.php");


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code with jquery autocomplete declaration?

Comment: Well, it is hard to understand where the problem is. Try to localize the problem. Comment all other autocomplete initializations except "search/province.php". Use firebug to see if you actually recieve data from province.php